# Google Recaptcha - Safari browser getting 0.1 score

Tags: recaptcha, captcha

I have implemented Google Recaptcha V3 on my site login page, I am getting success status as true and score 0.9 in the Google Chrome browser.

But in the Safari browser, I am always getting a score of 0.1.

I am using this URL: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify from the server side for site verify.

How to overcome this issue with Safari and all browsers?

Answer (score 0):

I having same problem, but can't find any help too. I think this is a problem with v3. In other similar problems that I found googling, one person told that is necessary some time for v3 to learning behavoir and automated tuning it. So, is necessary that your website goes live for some time to work correctly. And, he sugest to use v2 first and changing versions until all goes fine.